# Python: What is the fastest way to change the 3DView shading type in Blender Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way in Blender Python to change the 3D Viewport space ***shading.type*** or the ***shading.color_type*** directly?
I mean: without parsing all the screen areas for the 'VIEW_3D' type and change it then?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                space = area.spaces.active
                space.shading.type = 'SOLID'
                space.shading.color_type = 'MATERIAL'
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is the standard way to do it. There is no other way.

Comment: >>"There is no other way" —— Not quite so. You can avoid loops if you invoke your code as an operator (from a 3D Viewport). More details in my answer.

Comment: Since there can be multiple 3D views with different shading types, you inherently have to have some way to pick which one you want to change.

Comment: Agreed, both of the solutions presented in the Questions and Answer are valid, either you have to loop over all areas to find the ones you want, or you already know which one you're dealing with since you clicked a button in its layout interface

Comment: @Yaroslav yes ofcourse but I think the OP wanted a simple way to directly execute this without operator and needing a mouse hovered over the specific space, just like you can directly access `bpy.context.active_object` where Blender already knows that the context is no other space but 3D view. However with shading type it can be displayed differently for every 3D View area thus you inherently have to pick which one.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. in Blender you should to determine a context (one way or another)

If your mouse is hovering over a 3D Viewport - that counts as setting the context as 'VIEW_3D'.

So if you invoke your python code while your mouse is over a 3D Viewport - it would be enough just these 2 lines:

```
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'SOLID'
bpy.context.space_data.shading.color_type = 'MATERIAL'
```

But to invoke the code from a Viewport you should firstly register your code as an operator and then either:

1. add it to some menu
2. or just use F3.

You can learn more about operators from this video: [=link=](https://youtu.be/xscQ9tcN4GI?list=PLa1F2ddGya_8acrgoQr1fTeIuQtkSd6BW)